# How to use cairo to draw rectangle with top left and bottom right cut Corner?

Tags: c, math, drawing, cairo, pycairo

I tried to use cairo to draw a rectangle with top left and bottom right cut Corner, similar to Qt logo.

Here is what I want:
[image]
Here is what I get:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cairo.h>

int main()
{
    double height = 500, width = 250;

    cairo_surface_t *surface = cairo_image_surface_create (CAIRO_FORMAT_ARGB32, 500, 500);
    cairo_t *cr = cairo_create (surface);

    cairo_move_to(cr,0,0);
    cairo_line_to(cr,width,0);
    cairo_line_to(cr,width,height - height/4);
    cairo_line_to(cr,width - height/4,height);
    cairo_line_to(cr,0,height);

    cairo_set_line_width (cr, 10.0);
    cairo_set_line_cap (cr, CAIRO_LINE_CAP_ROUND);
    cairo_stroke (cr);

    cairo_destroy (cr);
    cairo_surface_write_to_png (surface, "hello.png");
    cairo_surface_destroy (surface);

    return 0;
}
```

I do not get the result that I want, someone can give a tip? Whatever the programming language I take.

Comment: You might add a bit more detail what is wrong with your result. Without reading the manual I would try to set the line properties before starting to draw. Specifying a color might also be useful.

Comment: Can you show us what is the behaviour you expect and what behaviour are you getting?

Comment: @John i just edit my post , can you check out ?

Comment: @Gerhardh the color of the borders and the background of the rectangle is not really important, I just wish to have a rectangle that looks like the logo of Qt

Comment: When I open the created file, it does not look like your shape. I don't get the left side closed and it the height is different. Your image seems distorted or created with different code

Comment: @Gerhardh it's just the left border that is not visible , but when I implement this function in another computer program (awesome wm in LUA) the left border appears so I ignored it

Comment: @Gerhardh  I just edit , if i  can get this shape it's okay for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your updated shape you are simply missing first stroke.
The remaining strokes need to be shifted to the right accordingly.

```
double cutoff = height/4.0;
cairo_move_to(cr, 0, cutoff);
cairo_line_to(cr, cutoff, 0);
cairo_line_to(cr, width + cutoff, 0);
cairo_line_to(cr, width + cutoff, height - cutoff);
cairo_line_to(cr, width, height);
cairo_line_to(cr, cutoff, height);
```

Comment: thank , do you have any advice on shapes ? and formulas to calculate

Comment: I don't have general rules for such shapes. I just draw them on paper (sometimes only in my mind), mark the lengths of the lines and start drawing.